# Comparison of 3 interventions with data measured yearly

Tags: time, compare, comparison, intervention

Thank you in advance for anyone's help. I took stats years ago, and now need to reteach myself for a project.

I have 3 groups with different interventions and measurements yearly over 6 years. I do not have pre-data.

Can I compare to see if there is a statistically significant difference between intervention efficacy?

I'm also thinking of using a Mann-Kendall.

Thank you!

Sorry its probably a basic stats question